# Разное отображение фона при смене разрешения экрана

Tags: css, photoshop

Подскажите, пожалуйста, заказчик прислал через psd-файл фон для сайта. На нём чёрный фон, на котором есть некоторые изображения (узоры). Когда я ставлю у себя на мониторе разрешение 1680x1050, всё хорошо видно. Когда же меняю его на более крупное - на 1920x1080, то остаётся просто чёрный фон без каких либо дополнительных изображений. Кто подскажет, в чём тут может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся Zoom, и увидишь все узоры.